# Show characters count while typing in textarea Angular 5

Tags: angular5, charactercount

I am trying to write a code to show characters count below the textarea field. I found many solutions for doing this but i don't know why its not working for me.

Here is the code what i am trying:

```
<div class="form-group border-0 describe mb-0">
  <label for="describewishInput" i18n="@@describewishLabel" class="text-capitalize">Describe Your Wish:</label>
    <span ngbTooltip="Please describe your wish here"
            placement="top" class="tt tt-bottom mt-1 mr-0"></span>
      <textarea type="text" (ngModel)="yourWish" id="yourWish" class="form-control mb-1" maxlength="255" i18n-placeholder="@@describeyourwish"></textarea>
      <span class="pull-right char"><em>{{ 255 - yourWish.length }} characters left</em></span>
</div>
```

Here is the error i am getting

```
SignupFormComponent.html:121 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SignupFormComponent.html:122)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

Can you help me with this. Its very frustrating as i am working on it from 1 day.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977022/3281522

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two way data binding **`[(ngModel)]`** ,

```
<textarea type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourWish" id="yourWish" class="form-control mb-1" maxlength="255" i18n-placeholder="@@describeyourwish"></textarea>
```

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cukbqm)

Comment: I tried ` [(ngModel)]="yourWish"` and now i am getting this error:
`SignupFormComponent.html:121 ERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>
    In your class:
    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
      Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:`

Comment: Check the demo above

Comment: I did checked the demo, but using this code gives me above error

Comment: set this to the input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: I used it like `<textarea type="text"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="yourWish" id="yourWish" class="form-control mb-1" maxlength="255" i18n-placeholder="@@describeyourwish"></textarea>` and still getting the same error

Comment: please search for the above error you will get 100 answers saying the fix